# How to query for rows that have a distinct boolean value

Tags: sql

Given I have a database table with a column containing strings and a column containing booleans, how can I query to find if there are any rows that have the same value in the string column but different values in the boolean column?

For example, given the following:

```
| some_string_column | some_boolean_column|

| value1             | true               |
| value1             | false              |
| value2             | true               |
| value2             | true               |
```

I am interested in value1 because it has rows with both a true and a false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `group by` clause:

```
select some_string_column
from some_table
group by some_string_column
having count(distinct some_boolean_column) > 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dc99/1)

Comment: If you wouldn't have been busy on edited his question then maybe you would have bit him:) @jarlh

Comment: @jarlh -- ha, I guess my page refreshed faster :) And I tried to edit it -- you beat me there!

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT some_string_column
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY some_string_column
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT some_boolean_column) > 1
```